# Make Bootstrap dropdown button center align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

How colud i make bootstrap dropdown button on center.

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
     keep searching our site listening audio episodes
     <span class="fa fa-play pull-right"></span>
   </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu col-md-6" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your demo link?

Comment: on css  

.dropdown{  margin: 0 auto;}  .dropdown-toggle{ text-align: center}

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your code

```
.dropdown-toggle{position: relative;}
.fa-play{position: absolute;
    margin: 0px auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through below code.

I have added `style="line-height: 20px;vertical-align:middle;"` to span

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
 keep searching our site listening audio episodes
 <span class="fa fa-play pull-right" style="line-height: 20px;vertical-align:middle;"></span>
   </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu col-md-6" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```